# Recursive Function to Record Key path in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, recursion

good afternoon.

I'm hoping someone can assist me with this function I'm trying to define, I looked through already asked questions that were similar, but this is unfortunately still not clear to me.

My goal is to recursively go through a nested dictionary and record the keypath needed to reach each final key.

So if I have this dic for instance:

```
    example_dic = {
    "fruitType": 'apple',
    "orderNumber": 12345,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": 'https://foo'
        }
    },
    "customerName": 'bob'
}
```

The desired output (which for now I'm just printing) would be something like

```
fruitType
orderNumber
links self href
customerName
```

This is what I've accomplished so far:

```
def get_key_path(to_find_keys, key_path):

for key in to_find_keys.keys():

    print key

    key_path.append(key) # Append to list
    try:
        get_key_path(to_find_keys[key], key_path) # About to call function recursively 

    except AttributeError:

        print key_path # Found last key, print it.
        key_path = []  # Reset list
```

Right now it does find each last key in the dic successfully, but I'm having trouble resetting the list. If my dic has a lot of entries and nests, the list resets at the wrong moment.

I'm still learning a lot about Python (and programming in general) so maybe there's a fundamental element about recursion I'm missing.

Many thanks in advance for anyone that can help out!

Comment: "I'm still learning a lot about Python (and programming in general)" -- which makes your choice of using Python 2 odd. Beyond maintaining legacy code, there are few good reasons to be using Python 2 in 2021. If you are still learning Python, why not learn the type which is still being actively maintained?

Comment: @JohnColeman, thank you! I appreciate the suggestion, indeed I agree Python 2 is not ideal these days, but I have to deal with it because my job still has a lot of stuff tied to it that ins't transitioned yet. However, 3 is in fact what I'll be focusing on.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a recursive generator.  Go throuth keys and values of the dictionary and recurse for values that are dictionaries. just yield the key for values that aren't dictionaries.

```
def keyPaths(d):
    for k,sd in d.items():
        if isinstance(sd,dict):
            yield from (f"{k} {sub}" for sub in keyPaths(sd))
        else:
            yield k
```

output:

```
example_dic = {
    "fruitType": 'apple',
    "orderNumber": 12345,
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": 'https://foo'
        }
    },
    "customerName": 'bob'
}

for path in keyPaths(example_dic):
    print(path)

fruitType
orderNumber
links self href
customerName
```

Comment: This totally did it! Thank you so much Alain.